# Message history not getting deserialized

Tags: spring-integration

I was trying to send message history via kafka backed message channel, and i am getting an error like below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect type specified for header 'history'. Expected [class org.springframework.integration.history.MessageHistory] but actual type is [class org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper$NonTrustedHeaderType]
at org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders.get(MessageHeaders.java:216)
at org.springframework.integration.history.MessageHistory.write(MessageHistory.java:96)
```

Environment:

- Java version: JDK8
- Kafka version: 3.1.0
- Spring-boot-starter-integration: 2.6.2 (integration core:5.5.7)

The message is getting deserialized properly without message history, but unable to do so with message history.

Here is the configuration that I am setting:

Consumer:

```
  public ConsumerFactory consumerFactory(String groupId, String clientId) {
    Properties consumerProperties = new Properties();
    consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG);
    consumerProperties
        .put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());

    consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId);
    consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG);
    consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG);

    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory defaultKafkaConsumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(
        consumerProperties);

    JsonDeserializer jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer(GenericMessage.class, JacksonJsonUtils.messagingAwareMapper());

    jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
    defaultKafkaConsumerFactory.setValueDeserializer(jsonDeserializer);
    return defaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
  }
```

Producer:

```
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> producerConfigMap = new HashMap<>();
    producerConfigMap.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    producerConfigMap.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, PRODUCER_LINGER_MS_CONFIG);
    producerConfigMap.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, PRODUCER_COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG);
    producerConfigMap.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, PRODUCER_BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG);
    producerConfigMap
        .put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

    JsonSerializer<GenericMessage> jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer(JacksonJsonUtils.messagingAwareMapper());

    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory defaultKafkaProducerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(
        producerConfigMap);

    defaultKafkaProducerFactory.setValueSerializer(jsonSerializer);
    return defaultKafkaProducerFactory;
  }
```

ConcurentKafkaContainerListenerFactory:

```
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
      String groupId, String clientId) {

    DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper kafkaHeaderMapper = new DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper();
    kafkaHeaderMapper.addTrustedPackages("org.springframework.integration.history");

    MessagingMessageConverter messagingMessageConverter = new MessagingMessageConverter();
    messagingMessageConverter.setHeaderMapper(kafkaHeaderMapper);

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(groupId, clientId));
    factory.setMessageConverter(messagingMessageConverter);
    return factory;
  }
```

I have tried adding trusted packages in every possible way, but still, I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks at the exception again: `org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper$NonTrustedHeaderType`. It doesn't say that something is wrong with your (de)serializers. It is a `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` mapper feature to ban that type from you.

You need to supply a `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` with the `addTrustedPackages("*")` on the consumer side. If you use `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`, see its `setMessageConverter(MessageConverter messageConverter)` to be populated with the `MessagingMessageConverter`. And that one has an option for the `setHeaderMapper(KafkaHeaderMapper headerMapper)`, where you already can set that `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper`.

Please, raise a GH, so we can add that `org.springframework.integration.history` to trusted packages for a default `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` in the `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have updated my question by adding a section i.e  "ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory". Also tried setting message-converter with ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory , but still, it is not working.

Comment: Raised a GH https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3734

Comment: How do you use that `kafkaListenerContainerFactory`? The `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` has to use your customized `AbstractMessageListenerContainer`

Comment: As I said: you have to use this `public void setMessageConverter(MessageConverter messageConverter) {` on the `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. The real processing is happened in the `IntegrationRecordMessageListener`. So, that `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` is fully not involved.

Comment: I am using ```kafkaListenerContainerFactory``` to create ```SubscribableKafkaChannel```

Comment: Is there any way to use `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdaper` with `SubsribableKafkaChannel` ?

Comment: I see. OK. That's different story. The `SubscribableKafkaChannel` has to be supplied with an external `MessageConverter`. Right now it does not. Sorry. Will update our GH issue on the matter.